# Going about Testing an SSL Connection on RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, ssl, rabbitmq

Trying to Connect to Rabbitmq://uri:port/ on an SSL enabled port

```
string sslDir = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\temp");
        if (null == sslDir)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SSL_CERT_DIR is not configured, skipping test");
            return;
        }
        cf.Ssl.ServerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        cf.Ssl.CertPath = sslDir + "cert.cer";
        cf.Ssl.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            var conn = cf.CreateConnection();
            var ch = conn.CreateModel();
            Console.WriteLine("Press key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine("Press key");
            Console.ReadKey();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Throws an exception with the following stacktrace. We have tried several ssl configurations to connect. The two most prominent methods described in

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_HOST"],
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_PORT"]),
            UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_USERNAME"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"],
            VirtualHost = "MyHostName",
SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch |
SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors,
},
```

Tried the following method to configure SSL using a certificate from the Server's root myservercert.cer as below.

```
Ssl = new RabbitMQ.Client.SslOption("MYHOST", @"C:\temp\myservercert.cer", true),
AmqpUriSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
};
```

and additionally another SSL Configurator.

```
                Ssl = new SslOption()
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ServerName = "MyServer.com",
                AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch |
                                         SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors,
            },
```

But we get the following exception :

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.SslOption.get_Certs()
   at RabbitMQ.Client.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption sslOption)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, Int32 connectionTimeout, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
```

Most of the SSL Configuration Settings are taken care of by us. For instance, the following parameters are ensured for accuracy

- Username
- Password
- PortNumber
- Host
- VirtualHostName

However We do not have user friendly error messages. The exact settings required is kind of undebuggable.

The exact snippet of code I use is below.

```
var cf = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_HOST"],
            Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_PORT"]),
            UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_USERNAME"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_PASSWORD"],
            VirtualHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RABBITMQ_VIRTUALHOSTNAMES"],
            RequestedHeartbeat = 300,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = false
        };
```

Is there a way to debug rabbitmq connections on powershell or shell?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html